# How to upgrade Symfony 5 LDAP security to the new Authenticator-based

Tags: php, symfony, security, ldap, symfony5

I'm successfully used LDAP auth with some settings:

```
security:
    # enable_authenticator_manager: true

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
   
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true

            form_login_ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                provider: app_user_provider
                dn_string: 'OFFICE\{username}' # 'OFFICE\{username}'
                
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
```

and some settings in services.yaml and it was worked fine!

But i have trouble with [Using the new Authenticator-based Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html#authenticators-removed-authentication-providers). How can i read *The authentication providers are refactored into Authenticators*, but i can't see no one example how to refactor something like LdapUserProvider.

Does anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: Its recommended to read symfony docs really carefully because there might be informatiion in every small sentence. There are no guides on how to refactor. Basicalliy you just have to implement the interface `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AuthenticatorInterface` and thats it. The link you posted also continues to describe how to use this interface and change the behaviour of authentication etc.

Comment: Yeah, i read about, but have not any idea how to refactor ldap provider using AuthenticatorInterface. They seems much different.

Comment: Unless you really want to learn the intricacies of ldap authentication then I would suggest waiting a few months.  By then there should be some good examples or bundles available.  This is fairly new functionality and it will take the eco-system a bit of time to catch up.  Your existing code will continue to work just fine.  Just get those annoying deprecation notices.  If you did want to try rolling your own then I would suggest creating a new 5.3 project and building it there.  The two security systems do not co-exist very well.